# Why the order of options of dropdown box get changed?

Tags: html, struts2

I have following MAP which is populating my dropdown list; however, it changes the order of the options.

```
public static final Map SIZE = new TreeMap(){
        {
            put("-1"," ");
            put("100","100m2");        
            put("200","200m2");        
            put("300","300m2");        
            put("400","400m2");        
            put("500","500m2");        
            put("600","600m2");        
            put("700","700m2");        
            put("800","800m2");        
            put("900","900m2"); 
            put("1000","1000m2");                
        }
        ;
    };


 <s:select name="size"  label="Size" list="@com.example.Lists@SIZE"/>
```

**Options in dropbox**

```
 100m2
 1000m2
 200m2
 300m2 
 ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TreeMap is sorted based on the natural order of the keys. Try changing your keys to integer:

```
public static final Map SIZE = new TreeMap(){
        {
            put(-1," ");
            put(100,"100m2");        
            put(200,"200m2");        
            put(300,"300m2");        
            put(400,"400m2");        
            put(500,"500m2");        
            put(600,"600m2");        
            put(700,"700m2");        
            put(800,"800m2");        
            put(900,"900m2"); 
            put(1000,"1000m2");                
        }
        ;
    };


 <s:select name="size"  label="Size" list="@com.example.Lists@SIZE"/>
```